# ScreenFlow won't record screen after transferring data to new MacBook Pro running Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, privacy, screen-recording

I've just bought a new 16" MacBook Pro and I've transferred all my data, but now [ScreenFlow](https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) won't record the screen anymore.

It must be a permission problem, so I've opened System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Screen Recording but I can't add ScreenFlow:

[image]

**Can someone help me to add ScreenFlow again to the authorized list?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Apps appear in the "Screen Recording" section once they have requested the permission. You can't add any apps. What happens when you try to record the screen with Screenflow? Do you get an error message? Or nothing happens?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem by using the following command in Terminal:

```
tccutil reset All net.telestream.screenflow9
```

Then restarted the Mac.